# WAVE error: Linked image missing alternative text

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c

The image inside this anchor tag throws a "Linked image missing alternative text" error in the [WAVE accessibility checker](https://wave.webaim.org/):

```
<a href="www.google.com" title="google link"><img src="google.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Well, your `alt` attribute *is* blank

Comment: yeah, but i dont need any alt text. I need title attribute on the anchor tag so i could see text on hover. If i add something in alt text then screenreader will read couple of times.

Comment: Title attribute is not reliably announced, Adam’s answer gives good advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a decorative image being the sole element of a link. This image is a link, it's not decorative.

```
<a href="www.google.com" title="google link"><img src="google.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

When an image is the only content inside the link, its alternative should contain the link destination description.

**In other cases**, adding the `role="presentation"` would have been sufficient to explicitely state that you willingly wanted a decorative image **which is not the case here**.

Comment: adding role="presentation" to the anchor still shows wave error. @Adam

Comment: @nag37 Yes, of course, that's why I specified that it would have been a solution "in other cases". Here, you have to set the `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Support for the `title` attribute in screen readers and other assistive technologies is extremely limited; it is also useless for sighted keyboard users.

See for example,

- [Don't Rely on the Title Attribute for Accessibility](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/dont-rely-title-attribute-accessibility-seo) (2016)
- [Using the HTML title attribute – updated](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/) (2013)

If a link contains only an image and no text, the content of the `alt` attribute constitutes link's "link text", i.e. this is what a screen reader will announce when the link receives focus. For this reason, the `alt` attribute cannot be empty in this case. You need something like the following:

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="google.jpg" alt="Google" /></a>
```

If you include actual text next to the image, as in the following example, you can leave the `alt` attribute empty:

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="google.jpg" alt="" />Google</a>
```

In the last example, the image can be treated as a decorative one, due to the presence of proper link text. If the string `Google` were included in the `alt` attribute, it would be announced twice by a screen reader.

Adding a `title` attribute to the link is not a great idea for the following reasons:

1. It is useless to sighted keyboard users who cannot hover the mouse pointer over the link.
2. Screen reader support for the `title` attribute is not entirely consistent, as can be seen from the test results [A "click here" link with TITLE attribute: Screen reader compatibility](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/a-title/) (last updated in April 2019). Adding the attribute `title="google link"` to the above examples would just lead to needless repetition in those screen reader and browser combinations that actually support that attribute on links.